# Pasar datos de un formulario a un datagrid en otro formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Necesito pasar datos de un formulario a un datagrid en otro formulario, la idea es que se cierre un formulario y se abra el otro, pero al ocupar Hide() y ShowDialog()
solo se puede agregar un registro, al hacerlo nuevamente se borra el anterior y se vuelve a registrar el nuevo, alguna solución?, no tengo base de datos implementada aún

Answer (score 0):

Si al abrir el form del grid usas el `new` crearas una nueva instancia por lo tanto no conserva el valor que pudieran agregar en una operacion anterior

Aqui hay varias formas de resolverlo

- Abrir el form hijo la primera vez y luego usar siempre la misma instancia del form
- asignar los datos a una variable global, de esta forma si cierras el form hijo no pierdes los datos y puedes volver a cargarlos cuando se abra nuevamente

Para la primera opcion podrias hacer algo como ser

```
private FormHijo frmHijo = null;


public void button1_Click(...){

    if(frmHijo == null){
        frmHijo = new FormHijo();
    }

    frmHijo.Show();
}
```

Para la segunda opcion podrias definir una `class` en un `.cs` y alli asignar los datos

```
public class GlobalData
{
    public static DataTable Datos {get;set;}
}
```

entonces desde el form hijo antes de cerrar podrias asignar la informacion asi no la pierdes

```
public formhijo_Closing(...)
{
    var dt = DataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    GlobalData.Datos = dt;
}
```

si asignas los datos cuando cierras el forma podras recuperarlo cual lo vuelves abrir

Pero usas una tecnica o la otra, no aplican ambas juntas

O conservas la instancia del form hijo y usas siempre la misma, o conservas la instancia de los datos del grid y los asignas y recuperas cuando el form hijo se instancia nuevamente